# Is there an OpenSSL function or callback that can be used to determine when the TLS handshake is finished

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have written separate client and server applications that use OpenSSL to exchange encrypted data.  Both applications work.  The only minor issue I have involves the client application.  SSL_is_init_finished returns true after the client receives the first TLS handshake message.  I need something that can be used to verify that the client has received the second (assumed to be last) TLS handshake message.  Does the OpenSSL API provide a method?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "second TLS handshake message"? An handshake can use various messages, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake  so depending on cases many messages can happen. It is also different by TLS version (and you didn't specify it), since TLS 1.3 handshake uses different messages.

Comment: As for callbacks, see https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_set_info_callback.html.  Did you try to use "SSL_CB_HANDSHAKE_DONE" and didn't that map to your needs? If so, why/how? You will need to provide specific code to show what you did, as well as the handshake in some form, if you want people to debug it...

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  Your second response answered the question.